# flask-sqlalchemy-postgres db insert failing

Tags: postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using Flask with SQLAlchemy and PostGresDB and getting this error on an insert;

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'dict' 
[SQL: 'SELECT results.id AS results_id,......]
```

models.py is as follows (just the ORM)

```
class Result(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'results'

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
url = db.Column(db.String())
cities = db.Column(JSON)
states = db.Column(JSON)
```

app.py for the insert part is;

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

frequency_cities = Counter(city_pop) # dict object 
frequency_states = Counter(state_pop) # dict object

try:
    from models import Result
    result = Result(
        url= url,
        cities=frequency_cities, 
        states=frequency_states 
    )
    db.session.add(result)
    db.session.commit()
    return result.id
except:
    errors.append("Unable to add item to database.")
    return {"error": errors}
```

I am at a loss.

Comment: Are you sure this is the right code? You are trying to add a record but the SQL error shows a select

Comment: yes, I am seeing the "except"  (from the db insert "try/except" block ) message in the error and when I query the DB there are no records. I am not sure why the select shows up in the error, anyways I restarted all the services and now it is working!

Comment: Hello! Are fix your error?